# Agda record parse error

Tags: agda

Agda gives me a parse error when trying to type check this:

```
record Monad (M : Set → Set) : Set1 where
  field return  : {A : Set} → A → M A  
        _>>=_   : {A B : Set} → M A → (A → M B) → M B
```

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I've tried flipping the order of the fields while commenting out the bottom one and it type checks => I'm not using correct record,field syntax i guess

EDIT2:

```
record Monad (M : Set → Set) : Set1 where
  field 
    bind   : {A B : Set} → M A → (A → M B) → M B 
    return : {A : Set} → A → M A
```

Okay I fiddled around some more and it started working. Formatted like above. Putting this in an edit since I still don't know what caused my original snippet to not work.

Comment: Your code works just fine. Perhaps you are using tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: Mm.. it was something. I fiddled around some more when showing a classmate my code and suddenly it worked. Jeezz... thanks for your concern (including all your other most useful agda anwers here)

Comment: Glad you got it to work. I'm using development version of Agda, so it's possible that the parser was changed.

Comment: Perhaps a tabs-vs-spaces problem?  It might help if you quote the actual error in your question...